# Find all different combinations of learning subjects that have unique conditions

Tags: c#, math

It's a college task. I Know how to find permutation of numbers, letters etc., but this is completely different. Here's the task :

A Student is studying in a university. All study modules (subjects) are selective. All need to be picked. Some modules can be selected only after certain modules are picked. The student need to form a study program, in which the modules would form a list. Modules that make up the list depend on the earlier picked modules. Create a program that would arrange all possible lists. Data file is arranged like so  ( first line is the number of modules) : Module code, Module name, Number of modules that the given depends on, dependent modules codes;

```
9
IF01 Programming 0
IF02 Maths 1 IF01
IF03 Data structures 2 IF01 IF02
IF04 Digital logic 0
IF05 Mathematical logistics 1 IF04
IF06 Operations optimization 1 IF05
IF07 Algorithm analysis 2 IF03 IF06
IF08 Programming theory 1 IF03
IF09 Operating systems  2 IF07 IF08
```

Result file example of one possible list (a list with module codes and their names):

```
IF01 Programming 
IF04 Digital logic 
IF02 Maths
IF03 Data structures
IF08 Programming theory 
IF05 Mathematical logistics
IF06 Operations optimization
IF07 Algorithm analysis
IF09 Operating systems
```

There can be less or more modules. The Files are just examples. The program should be generalized. It says there should also be a use of recurring methods.

Please help. Have no idea how to form the conditions.

Comment: It seems like a tree of some sort would be the best way to represent this data.

Comment: @Abion47 - It's a Directed Acyclic Graph, not a tree.

Comment: @Enigmativity Ah yes, wrong terminology. Graph, not tree.

Comment: An interesting Packing problem with a twist.  You still do standard permutation.  Standard permutation assumes an item gets removed once it is used so you no longer can pick item.  Normally permutation  has a list of items which you pick from then discards the item after you pick.  In this problem when you have more than one class you remove the first class and continue with out removing the subject

Comment: It seems like a question of picking one from the list (and automatically picking all prerequisites) and then picking another recursively until the entire set is picked, and then returning all generated permutations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do it is the following, explained in the code (I hope the comments are explicit, but if not, tell me).

The principle is to formalize a module as an object that contains the other modules it depends on.

Then each step, try to find the possible modules and generate the permutation of them.

When all modules are "consumed" we have a solution.

```
// Defines a module as having a name and a list of modules it depends on to be eligible
class Module
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Module> DependsOn { get; set; }
}

// Represents a solution as a list of modules
class Solution
{
    public List<Module> Modules { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        // Defines the modules
        var if01 = new Module() { Name = "IF01" };
        var if02 = new Module() { Name = "IF02" };
        var if03 = new Module() { Name = "IF03" };
        var if04 = new Module() { Name = "IF04" };
        var if05 = new Module() { Name = "IF05" };
        var if06 = new Module() { Name = "IF06" };
        var if07 = new Module() { Name = "IF07" };
        var if08 = new Module() { Name = "IF08" };
        var if09 = new Module() { Name = "IF09" };

        // Defines on which other modules each module depends on
        if01.DependsOn = new List<Module>();
        if02.DependsOn = new List<Module>() { if01 };
        if03.DependsOn = new List<Module>() { if01, if02 };
        if04.DependsOn = new List<Module>();
        if05.DependsOn = new List<Module>() { if04 };
        if06.DependsOn = new List<Module>() { if05 };
        if07.DependsOn = new List<Module>() { if03, if06 };
        if08.DependsOn = new List<Module>() { if03 };
        if09.DependsOn = new List<Module>() { if07, if08 };

        // The list of all modules
        var allModules = new List<Module>() { if01, if02, if03, if04, if05, if06, if07, if08, if09 };
        // The list of choosen modules at this step
        var choosenModules = new List<Module>();

        // Writes each found solution
        foreach ( var solution in Calculate( choosenModules, allModules ) )
        {
            solution.Modules.ForEach( m => Console.Write( m.Name + "/" ) );
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    // Determinates if a module is eligible considering already choosed modules
    static bool IsEligible( Module module, List<Module> alreadyChoosed )
    {
        // All modules this module depends on needs to be present in the allready choosen modules
        return module.DependsOn.All( m => alreadyChoosed.Contains( m ) );
    }

    static IEnumerable<Solution> Calculate( List<Module> choosenModules, List<Module> remainingModules )
    {
        if ( remainingModules.Count > 0 )
        // If some modules remain, we need to continue
        {
            // Takes the list of all eligible modules at this step
            var allEligibleModules = remainingModules.FindAll( m => IsEligible( m, choosenModules ) );

            // We explore the solutions
            foreach ( var newlyChoosen in allEligibleModules )
            {
                // Considering this newly choosen module...
                choosenModules.Add( newlyChoosen );
                // ... which is so no more in the remaining modules
                remainingModules.Remove( newlyChoosen );

                // And try to find all solutions starting with this newly choosen module
                foreach ( var solution in Calculate( choosenModules, remainingModules ) )
                    yield return solution;

                // As we have tested this module we push it back as unchoosed, so that the next possible will take its place in the solution
                choosenModules.Remove( newlyChoosen );
                remainingModules.Add( newlyChoosen );
            }
        }
        else
        // If no more remaining modules, we have a solution
            yield return new Solution() { Modules = new List<Module>( choosenModules ) };
    }
```

Comment: It should be not specific though. The data file is given just as an example, there can be more or less modules. The program should be generalized.

Comment: @Tom, the program is general except for the initialization step which could be done using a file... But the question was not "how to read a file" ?

Comment: I know how to read the file, but the task is to write a program that would only require you to upload a .txt file with the list of modules, and that it would give you a text file with all the possible combinations. I don't know how to optimize it like that. I also need to use recursion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to get permutation while using recursion. Don't know where to go further from here though, hope at least this helps.

```
 class Program
{
private static void Swap(ref char a, ref char b)
{
    if (a == b) return;

    a ^= b;
    b ^= a;
    a ^= b;
}

public static void GetPer(char[] list)
{
    int x = list.Length - 1;
    GetPer(list, 0, x);
}

private static void GetPer(char[] list, int k, int m)
{
    if (k == m)
    {
        Console.Write(list);
    }
    else
        for (int i = k; i <= m; i++)
        {
               Swap(ref list[k], ref list[i]);
               GetPer(list, k + 1, m);
               Swap(ref list[k], ref list[i]);
        }
}

static void Main()
{
    string str = "sagiv";
    char[] arr = str.ToCharArray();
    GetPer(arr);
}
```

}